# Bigquery - array index 5 is out of bounds

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am having two issues with my query. The idea of the query is to columnize the horizontal eventInfo data which will then be joined to another table with name specific data.

1. The below code works for one sessionId only. Without a where clause, I get this error: **Error: Array index 5 is out of bounds (overflow).**
   SOLVED. I mixed up column names. **The arg to ordinal wasnt the same one I was taking the max of.**
2. The second issue is, although I am taking the last row of almost all of the arrays, there is a names array which I want to unnest on top of final result. 
   The sample output returns one row for each sessionId, but if the names array has more than one value, *the final result should be one row for each person, per sessionId/date/checkin combo.* Im not sure why my unnesting of the names array is not working though...
   Now Im getitng a **Field name val does not exist in STRUCT**. This is on the names.val line.

Here is a base-line query:

```
with eventData as ( 
 select
 concat(fullVisitorId, ' ', cast(VisitId as string)) sessionId, date as date, 
 hit.hour as checkinHour, hit.minute as checkinMin,
 (select array_agg(hit.eventInfo.eventAction) from UNNEST(hits) hit where hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'foo') as foo_value,
 (select array_agg(struct(hit.eventInfo.eventAction)) as val from UNNEST(hits) hit where hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'submit_checkin') as names
 FROM  `web-analytics.192016109.ga_sessions_20191223`,
 UNNEST(hits) as hit
 )
 select 
 sessionId, date, 
 max(checkinHour) chkHr, max(checkinMin) as chkMin, # end of transaction
 max(foo_value[ordinal(ARRAY_LENGTH(foo_value))]) as foo_value, 
 names.val
 from eventData,
 unnest (names) as names
 group by sessionId, date
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated as I am not an expert in this syntax. 
Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to use names.eventAction instead of names.val. This is because the val struct is flattened out when I unnest names. So technically did not exist anymore. 
Also I assumed val was the name of the fields, but val is the name of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

For the first item, you`re probably dealing with null values that were supposed to be an array. The index out of bounds error is caused by the **ordinal** [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length)

For the second item, you should try to use left join instead of "," for example:

```
 from eventData left join
 unnest (names) as names
 group by sessionId, date
```

Intead of:

```
from eventData,
 unnest (names) as names
 group by sessionId, date
```

When you have `null` arrays you can lost some data performing `unnest`, so you can use `left join` in order to avoid that.

Just one question: are using the **names** column for anything? In your query this column seems to not have a reason for being there.

EDIT 1:

Try to use names.eventAction instead of names.val. Also, `LEFT JOIN` seems to be the best option.

```
with eventData as (   select  concat(fullVisitorId, ' ', cast(VisitId as string)) sessionId, date as date,   hit.hour as checkinHour, hit.minute as checkinMin,  (select array_agg(hit.eventInfo.eventAction) from UNNEST(hits) hit where hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'foo') as foo_value,  (select array_agg(struct(hit.eventInfo.eventAction)) as val from UNNEST(hits) hit where hit.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'submit_checkin') as names  FROM  `data-to-insights.ecommerce.web_analytics`,  UNNEST(hits) as hit )  select 
     sessionId, 
     date, 
     max(checkinHour) chkHr, max(checkinMin) as chkMin, # end of transaction
     max(foo_value[ordinal(ARRAY_LENGTH(foo_value))]) as foo_value, 
     names.eventAction name_val    from eventData left join  unnest (names) as names  group by sessionId, date, name_val
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response! I will try that today! I am using names, I just didnt want to overwhelm the code.

Comment: Please let me know if your problem was properly solved

Comment: Hello @rmesteves, I was able to resolve the first issue. For the second issue with names, I added it to the select (as you mentioned it wasnt being currently used) and then got the issue of **SELECT list expression references table alias names which is neither grouped nor aggregated**. But I cant group by the array 'names'. Im not sure what to try here. I also tried this with left join but it did not work

Comment: May you provide the complete query?

Comment: Hello @rmesteves, I have updated the query and provided the updated error message in section 2.

Comment: Hello. Try replacing names.val for names.eventAction since its the name of the field inside this struct. Also, when I run your query using LEFT JOIN, its brings me results, when I run using comma, it brings me no results. I`ll update the query in my answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didnt see your comment about eventAction